# Why "const int" to "int" conversion works but "const char[]" to "char *" does not

Tags: c++, char, int, type-conversion, constants

That is something that always intrigued me with the C++ language. With the appearance of the "const" identifier, it was supposed to replace the use of #define statement to declare constants. But as I stated to use them, I ended up in a const char to char conversion error madness.

Recently, I stated doing in class constants like done in Java. So I decided to declare something like this.

```
private: const static int NB_FIELD = 22;
```

This works perfectly. A function returning a int can return a "const int" without any problems.

But now if I try to do the same with a string like this:

```
private: static const char ERRORSTR [ 6 ];
```

Which constains the string "Error", it will generate const char to char conversion problems like in this function.

```
char* EnhancedSQLobject::get_SQLname ( int index )
{
   if ( index < p_nb_field && index >= 0 )
      return ( p_SQLfield_ptr [ index ] . SQLname)

   return ( ERRORSTR );

}
```

Now some people will say change the return value for const char* but I can't because if the index is valid, it will return a non-const variable, but if the index is invalid, it will return a constant error string.

So my choice are either to make the error string non-constant, or create a constant using #define statements. I remember a long time ago trying to define everything as a const char, but eventually it blew up somewhere else in the chains of conversion. Making it just easier to use regular char (the String class is not a option for me)

This is plain ridiculous, why implement a feature that only works for only a part of the variable types. I imagine it's related to the fact that stings are in fact table of characters so it probably return a pointer instead of a value.

Comment: "This is plain ridiculous, why implement a feature that only works for only a part of the variable types." - actually, that's not what's happening. In one case, you're talking about casting `const int` to `int`, but in the other case you're talking about `const char*` to `char*`, which has a level of indirection added.

Comment: You are comparing non-pointer-type to a pointer type. `T` cannot be compared to `T2 *`, assuming `T` and `T2` are basic types.

Comment: In one case, the `int` is copied. In the other, the pointer is copied, and since it points to constant data, why would the conversion work?

Comment: Just return nullptr on error. Problem fixed. :-) Anyway, the main use of `const` is not to replace `define`s to define constants. It's main use is for a function to guarantee it won't modify the caller's copy of its parameters (when passed by reference or pointer).

Comment: "You are comparing non-pointer-type to a pointer type." - That is what I thought. If I was doing the same with single characters it would not have been an issue.

Comment: "Just return nullptr on error." - That what I first thought, but I'll have problem finding bugs when it happens or it could crash if I display a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In one case you are talking about casting `const int` to `int`, while in the other you are casting `const char*` to `char*`. These really are different situations that should behave differently, because the latter has a level of indirection added (the pointer). You absolutely can cast a `const char` to a `char`, but that's not what you're doing.

Consider the following erroneous code:

```
const int i = 50;
int j = i;
int* p = &i; // ERROR
```

I attempt to do `int j = i;` and that is fine. The original `i` object remains `const` and the `j` object is given the same value as `i`.  However, if I attempt to do `int* p = &i;`, we have a problem. If this would compile, we would have `p` pointing at a const `int`, even though it tells us its pointing at a non-const `int`. This would allow us to modify the const object `i` through the pointer `p` - that's very bad.

You have the same situation here, just with `char`s. All of the `char`s in your `ERRORSTR` are `const`. You can't then return a `char*` that points at any of those `char`s, because that would be lying. The pointer isn't pointing at a non-const `char`, but at a `const` char.

`int`s and `char`s don't behave any differently in this respect.

However, I think you've only entered this predicament because of poor interface design. Why does your function return a special string when it can't find the "SQLname" (whatever that is)? What if, for example, the string "Error" was actually a valid name? How would the caller of the function tell the difference? I'd argue that if your function isn't able to fulfill the action of `get_SQLname` (that is, it isn't able to get the name), it should throw an exception.

On top of this, you should be using `std::string` instead of C-style `char*`s.

Comment: "What if, for example, the string "Error" was actually a valid name?" - IN fact that string is not interpreted by the computer. it's just that if I see this string on the screen or in the database, then I know that an error would have occured.

Comment: "On top of this, you should be using std::string instead of C-style char*s." - I have nothing against the string class in Java, but in C++ I try to avoid it, since I had so much trouble with it. In fact, I don't even use dynamic allocation unless I really desperately need it. Save me a lot of problems and bugs hard to find. Again in Java, I would not mind.

Comment: @larienna Huh? What kind of problems are you having with `std::string`? You shouldn't be doing any manual dynamic allocation with `std::string` at all.

Comment: I don't quite remember, I used it a long time ago. I don't even  use any standard container classes either. And since I am coding with allegro which is in C, I cannot Iostream strings to display them. It's an old program I am trying to finish, so I need to keep using old methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the two conversions. For `int`:

```
const int ci = 7;
int i = ci; // fine...
++i;        // ... because ci is still 7
```

But if you could do it for `char*`:

```
const char msg[] = "Hi";
char* p = msg; // not OK...
*p = 'B';      // ... because now msg = "Bi" 
               //     and it was supposed to be const!
```

The actual equivalent to the former for pointers would be:

```
char * const cc = someBuf();
char * c = cc; // this is totally OK
++c;           // ... because we're not modifying cc in any way
```

It's the difference between a const pointer and a pointer to const.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, using a `#define` will not work as you expect it will, at least not if you're truly using C++ and not C.

In C++, a string literal is `const`, thus if you declare:

```
#define ERRORSTR "ERROR"
```

And you try to `return ERRORSTR` from `get_SQLname`, it may cause undefined behavior if you try to modify the returned string. It's quite likely that your compiler is only issuing a warning for this because this fact that string literals are `const` was not always true in C++ a long time ago.

```
#include <iostream>

#define BLAH "blah"

char *foo() {
    return BLAH;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

On my compiler, I see the following warning:

```
so.cpp:6:12: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

The reality is that using `#define` for constants, especially string constants is unsafe for exactly this reason, and thus should be avoided. `const` provides you with some level of safety by the compiler, and if the compiler is telling you that the conversion is unsafe, there is a reason for that error, and you should try to figure out what that reason is and solve the problem instead of just trying to silence the error or find some other workaround. In fact, relying on behavior from C is generally a code smell in C++ and relying on the semantics of another language like Java is even worse. Despite their similarities in syntax, Java, C, and C++ are all very different from each other in their actual semantics. It would be best for you to learn those differences instead of just trying to apply the knowledge you know from one language to another.